# Trying to find a DateTime value that timeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime(value) will return `true`

Tags: .net, datetime

I'm trying to test some code I've got that is testing for a `timeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime(value)` which will return `true`.

I'm not having much luck finding a `DateTime` value :(

[Checking some daylight savings info](http://www.australia.gov.au/about-australia/facts-and-figures/time-zones-and-daylight-saving), it says that, for East-coast of Australia, daylight savings ended on the first Sunday in April. In 2016, this looks like it was `2016-04-03`.

> It ends at 2am (which is 3am Daylight Saving Time) on the first Sunday in April, when clocks are put back one hour.

So, I'm just not getting this right.

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
var result = timeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime(value);
```

Comment: why do you want this ? what's the goal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you give such a value yourself! If DST ends at 2016-04-03 02:00 local time, then that particular point in time (and the hour after it) is ambiguous if we had no time zone information (specifically, if we only knew it was local time, but not whether DST was in effect):

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
var result = timeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime(
   new DateTime(2016, 04, 02, 16, 00, 00, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
);
Console.WriteLine(result);  // True
```

Note that this is true even though we're specifying the time as UTC (2016-04-03 02:00 AEST is 2016-04-02 16:00 UTC). If the time kind is `Unspecified`, it will be taken as-is (so `new DateTime(2016, 04, 03, 02, 00, 00, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)` is ruled to be ambiguous) and if the time kind is `Local`, it is interpreted as a time in whatever time zone is currently in effect (which, for me, is not any in Australia).

Comment: Hmmm... I was setting the datetime 'kind' value as `Unspecified`. You are setting it as utc. hmmmm...

Comment: Can you explain how that date/time value, when the `Kind` is set to UTC .. would then return `true` for Ambiguous, please? I would have thought the `kind` would have to be `local` or `unspecified` (which would then take the kind-value of local..)

Comment: Well, you think wrongly, and that's why I deliberately used `Utc` -- to demonstrate that the API doesn't care. It only answers the question of whether a given point in time, *had we not had time zone info for it*, would be ambiguous *in the requested time zone*. That's why you can supply a UTC date and still have it work -- it will just calculate what that time is in the specified time zone, and then adjudicate the question of ambiguousness.

Comment: @Pure.Krome: updated my answer to hopefully clarify things.